# Python Dash: loading pandas dataframes into data table

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I have been trying to build an app with [Dash](https://plot.ly/products/dash/) recently, but despite looking through the many guides, I simply cannot figure out how to import a pandas dataframe into Dash's data table (which is essentially a pandas dataframe, except web-hosted and reactive).

Most examples illustrate how to manually pick certain columns/rows taken from a dataframe which is already hardcoded within the example, like in [here](https://dash.plot.ly/datatable). However, in, my situation, the dataframe is built within my code (and pandas is the easiest way to do this), so I end up having to figure out a way to convert a `pd.Dataframe()` into a `dash_table.DataTable()`.

How can I make this work? Using the references, I’ve tried the following code to send a dict of my dataframe to `dash_table.DataTable()`, but nothing displays.

My code:

```
## Imports
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table

from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

## Custom functions that creates the pandas dataframe
from twitter_functions import old_tweets

app = dash.Dash(dev_tools_hot_reload=True)
app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
app.config['suppress_callback_exceptions'] = True


app.layout = html.Div(children=[

    html.H3('Twitter App'),

    dcc.Input('ScreenName_Input', type='text'),

    html.Button(id='screenNames_submit_button', children='Submit'),

    dash_table.DataTable(id='tweet_table')

])

@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='tweet_table', component_property='data'),
    [Input(component_id='screenNames_submit_button', component_property='n_clicks_timestamp')],
    [State(component_id='ScreenName_Input', component_property='value')]
)
def display_tweets(submit_button, screen_names):
    tweets = old_tweets(screen_names)

    return tweets.to_dict(orient='records')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After [someone](https://community.plot.ly/t/loading-pandas-dataframe-into-data-table-through-a-callback/19354) also replied to me on the plotly forums (thankfully), it seems the final answer is to pre-set one's Data Table with the columns of the pandas dataframe that is going to go into it at some point, like this,

```
dash_table.DataTable(
    id='table',
    columns=[
    {'name': 'Column 1', 'id': 'column1'},
    {'name': 'Column 2', 'id': 'column2'},
    {'name': 'Column 3', 'id': 'column3'},
    {'name': 'Column 4', 'id': 'column4'},
    {'name': 'Column 5', 'id': 'column5'}]
)
```

, and then send in a dict of your pandas dataframe.

Comment: that code hugely helped. i don’t know why, but, only the files in the same directory are being displayed(“file not found” error for files that are not in local directory).

what i think is happening, is the file that’s being dragged/chosen is parsed as “file_name.csv”(which works fine for files in local directory) but not as “C:\Users\\**\\**\\*\\file_name.csv”. and that “file not found” error will not persist only if full path will be taken. how do i fix this?

Comment: please help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58990502/dashpython-cant-display-dataframe-in-datatable-after-calculations

Comment: I'll comment and then you should tell me if my comment ends up working for you.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your tweets function returns a dataframe,
adding table columns as a second output to your callback should work.

```
@app.callback(
    [Output(component_id='tweet_table', component_property='data'),
     Output(component_id='tweet_table', component_property='columns')
    [Input(component_id='screenNames_submit_button', component_property='n_clicks_timestamp')],
    [State(component_id='ScreenName_Input', component_property='value')]
)
def display_tweets(submit_button, screen_names):
    tweets = old_tweets(screen_names)
    columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in tweets.columns]
    data = tweets.to_dict(orient='records')
    return data, columns
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution that worked for me:

```
     dt_col_param = []

     for col in output_df.columns:
            dt_col_param.append({"name": str(col), "id": str(col)})

    dash_table.DataTable(
            columns=dt_col_param,
            data=output_df.to_dict('records')
        )
```

My biggest problem was that my app kept throwing an exception on whatever I was trying to pass into the 'columns' argument for dash_table.DataTable(...).

Hopefully this will help with not having to hard-code anything.

Comment: So, assuming all of this is happening within a Dash callback, would the `dash_table.DataTable` be outputted into a `html.Div()`, or some other empty object waiting for it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a long shot and untested, but based on https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-datatable-using-callbacks/6756, it seems Dash DataTables implicitly require an initial value if you're going to modify them via callback.

Try changing this line:

```
dash_table.DataTable(id='tweet_table')
```

To this:

```
dash_table.DataTable(id='tweet_table', rows=[{}])
```

Comment: Though it didn't work, thanks for still replying to me; it just so happens `rows` was deprecated as an argument down the line.

Comment: @Coolio2654, sorry this didn't work, but I see you found a solution!

Answer (score 1):

> #### Was working on sample codes and this worked for me , this example might help u with your Query

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
import base64
import io

app = dash.Dash()

# app.scripts.config.serve_locally = True
# app.css.config.serve_locally = True

DF_GAPMINDER = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv'
)
DF_GAPMINDER = DF_GAPMINDER[DF_GAPMINDER['year'] == 2007]
DF_GAPMINDER.loc[0:20]

DF_SIMPLE = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    'y': [4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 6],
    'z': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']
})


dataframes = {'DF_GAPMINDER': DF_GAPMINDER,
              'DF_SIMPLE': DF_SIMPLE}


def get_data_object(user_selection):
    """
    For user selections, return the relevant in-memory data frame.
    """
    return dataframes[user_selection]


app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('DataTable'),
    html.Label('Report type:', style={'font-weight': 'bold'}),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='field-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': df, 'value': df} for df in dataframes],
        value='DF_GAPMINDER',
        clearable=False
    ),
    
    dash_table.DataTable(id='table')
])


@app.callback([Output(component_id='table', component_property='data'), 
             Output(component_id='table', component_property='columns')],
            [Input('field-dropdown', 'value')])
def update_table(user_selection):
    """
    For user selections, return the relevant table
    """
    
    df = get_data_object(user_selection)
    columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in df.columns]
    data = df.to_dict(orient='records')
    return data, columns


app.run_server()
```

Comment: this code does not work if the dataframe is a pivot table

Answer (score 0):

Dash Bootstrap Components can provide a way to directly import from a `DataFrame`:
https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/table/

```py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "First Name": ["Arthur", "Ford", "Zaphod", "Trillian"],
        "Last Name": ["Dent", "Prefect", "Beeblebrox", "Astra"],
    }
)

table = dbc.Table.from_dataframe(df, striped=True, bordered=True, hover=True)
```